# writing to text file - 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I'm having a bit of trouble outputting words from a text-image to a `.txt` file.

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance, ImageFilter

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("book_image.jpg"))

file = open("text_file","w")
file.write(text)
print(text)
```

The code which reads the image file and prints out the words on the image works fine. The problem is when I try to take the text and write it to file, I get the following error;

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 366: ordinal not in range(128)

Could anyone please explain how I can convert the variable `text` to a string?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
file = open("text_file", "w", encoding='utf8', errors="ignore")
```

Answer (score 0):

Also try:

```
file.write(text).encode('utf-8').strip()
```